# Passing extra arguments to XMLHttpRequest.onload

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I'm trying to comunicate with a server, using XMLHttpRequest in javascript.

How can I pass info to the onload function?

```
// global variable that containts server response
var reply;

var makeRequest = function(extraInfo) {
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.open(...);
  request.onload = handler;
};

var handler = function(data) {
  reply = data.target.response;
  console.log("Server Reply: " + reply);
};
```

How can I pass the parameter extraInfo from makeRequest to the handler function? (without using a global variable)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just use a closure in such way:

```
...
var makeRequest = function(extraInfo) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open(...);
    request.onload = function(data) {
        // extraInfo is accessible here
        reply = data.target.response;
        console.log("Server Reply: " + reply);
    };
};
```

Comment: This does work, but also violates rule 1 of [Callback Hell](http://callbackhell.com/): "keep your code shallow".

Answer (score 6):

I figured out that passing **extra info into the request handler** can be done this way: (At least is good for me)

```
    request.open(...);
    request.extraInfo = identifier;
    request.onload = function() {
        identifier = this.extraInfo;
    };
```

Comment: As the title of this article said, what my solution does is to allow to get extra parameters after receive the response. This problem doesn't exist if you use single calls, or use syncronous mode, because you may save any information in global variables before the call and get it after done.

Comment: Continue from previous comment.....
But when you use multiple asyncronous calls, then you need to know what response must be assigned to each reference, so you need this exta field.
A single aplication way is to use this field to enumerate each call as index of global storage, but as this is javascript, yoy may save here any kind of data.

Answer (score 4):

The accepted solution didn't work for me, but this did

```
const params = new FormData();
params.append('selectedValue', selectedValue);
const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('post', url, true);
xhr.send(params);
xhr.extraInfo = extraInfo;   // <- set your data here
xhr.onload = (e) => {
    const data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

    alert(xhr.extraInfo)   /// <- access it like this
    alert(e.target.extraInfo)  // <- or like this
    //return data;
};
```

Comment: "extraInfo" was not accessible where it says it should be. Simple as that